# Extra P tag is added in Single-Line-Text while updating from Experience Editor in Sitecore 9.3

Tags: experience-editor, glass-mapper

I am using Siteore 9.3 also using Glass mapper 5 and I have one Single-Line-Text and I am binding value just like mentioned below:

```
   <div class="heading-5 header-text">@Html.Glass().Editable(card, m => m.CardHeader)</div>
```

While I am updating value of Single-Line-Text from experience editor. It is adding extra P tag with text.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the issue with the current Sitecore.NET 9.3.0 (rev. 003498) without a hotfix mentioned by @Ed Lane (@ed-lane), and with the hotfix installed.
The behaviour still the same, the issue is not fixed, despite the fact that InlineEditingUtil.js was updated and contains a couple of improvements.

**Only single-line text was checked & patched**

The root cause: the P tag or DIV tag is added into empty input control, the tag depends on Sitecore setting

```
<setting name="HtmlEditor.LineBreak" value="p" />
```

**How to simulate the issue**

1. empty any single-line text input control to get [No text in field] there
2. add any text
3. save the page
4. P tag become visible, it was added into empty SPAN in this.checkEmptyEditableElement() method (or this.prepopulateEmptyElement() method in case of hotfix applied), see InlineEditingUtil.js for details

**How to fix the issue - the original version**

Open \sitecore\shell\Applications\Page Modes\InlineEditingUtil.js, **this.checkEmptyEditableElement()** method must be patched to avoid adding unwanted p tag into empty input:

```
this.checkEmptyEditableElement = function(target) {
...
    // start of patch - the condition added
    // to avoid adding unwanted p tag into empty single-line text input control
    if (target.getAttribute("scfieldtype") !== "single-line text") {
    // end of patch
        var node = document.createElement(newLineNode);
        range.insertNode(node);
        range.collapse(true);
        node.innerHTML = "<br />";
        range.selectNodeContents(node);

        selection.removeAllRanges();
        selection.addRange(range);
    // start of patch
    }
    // end of patch
...
};
```

**How to fix the issue - version with hotfix**

Open \sitecore\shell\Applications\Page Modes\InlineEditingUtil.js, **this.prepopulateEmptyElement()** and **this.getClosestFieldNode()** methods must be patched to avoid adding unwanted p tag into empty input:

```
this.prepopulateEmptyElement = function(target, fieldType) {
...
    } else
    // start of patch - the condition added
    // to avoid adding unwanted p tag into empty single-line text input control
    if (fieldType !== "single-line text")
    // end of patch
    {
        var newLineNode = Sitecore.WebEditSettings.newLineBreak;
        if (newLineNode.toLowerCase() == "p" || newLineNode.toLowerCase() == "div") {

            var node = document.createElement(newLineNode);
            range.insertNode(node);
            range.collapse(true);
            node.innerHTML = "<br />";
            range.selectNodeContents(node);

            selection.removeAllRanges();
            selection.addRange(range);
        }
    }
...
};

this.getClosestFieldNode = function(currentNode) {
    var result;

    // start of patch - to select valid sitecore container
    if (currentNode.nodeName == '#text')
    {
        currentNode = this.getClosestFieldNode(currentNode.parentElement);
    }
    // end of patch

    if (currentNode.getAttribute("scfieldtype") != null ||
        currentNode.tagName.localeCompare('body', 'en', { sensitivity: 'base' }) == 0) {
        result = currentNode;
    } else {
        result = this.getClosestFieldNode(currentNode.parentElement);
    }
    return result;
};
```

the code before the patch applied:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

We experienced the same issue with Multi-Line text.

Sitecore Support provided a Hotfix for this:

"*As a quick test, could you please install the hotfix available at the following URL and check if it helps:*

https://sitecore.box.com/s/nos0inc1v5dm6dzwau15mmgltnvdoplp

*Be aware that the hotfix was built specifically for **Sitecore 9.3.0 (Initial Release)**, and you should not install it on other Sitecore versions or in combination with other hotfixes, unless explicitly instructed by Sitecore Support.*

*Note that you need to extract ZIP file contents to locate installation instructions and related files inside it.*

*Unless stated differently in the installation instructions, the hotfix should be installed on CM instance and then synced with other instances using your regular development practices.*"

Hope this helps.

Comment: I checked the hotfix, but it seems to be the bug with <p> still there :(